# In current canon, which bounty hunters have actually beaten a Jedi?

Tags: star-wars, jedi, bounty-hunters

It doesn't matter if it's by outwitting them or besting them in a fair combat, but I'm looking for a direct, non-surprise confrontation.

Just managing to escape, sneak attacking while they are distracted, or keeping them busy while some other plot occurs away from the Jedi doesn't count as "beating" a Jedi.

**In a straight-up face-to-face confrontation, when has a Jedi ever lost to a bounty hunter in anything?**

Comment: define 'lost' - technically speaking, Fett outmatched Kenobi on Kamino and escaped

Comment: @NKCampbell He didn't down Kenobi, or capture him, or end in any position of power over Kenobi. They were both still fully capable of fighting but Fett used the opportunity to escape.

Comment: agree - in this case, Kenobi's goal was to capture Fett, who escaped, thus defeating Kenobi's goal :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Jango Fett killed the Jedi Master Coleman Trebor in Attack of the Clones with a simple hand-blaster.

Comment: Pretty sure that counts as 'Sneak attack while distracted'.

Comment: @Jeff - He sneaked up on him from the front?

Comment: I think because it happens so fast, I also just thought he had snuck up on Trebor. Looking at it on loop from that clip, over and over, I'm still not sure. He does manage to block a couple shots first, so maybe that does count as a real fight.

Comment: @Valorum - he attacked while the Jedi was distracted with facing down Dooku.  The Jedi was preparing to fight the known threat (the Jedi Master with legendary lightsaber skills) when he was attacked by Jango Fett.

Comment: Definitely support this answer.  He blocked the first two shots, there was no interference preventing him from blocking the next two as well.  He may have been surprised, but it wasn't a surprise attack (Fett doesn't even move his feet from what we can see, even in longer clips than this).

Comment: Amusingly, this question was spawned from another question about the competency of Jango Fett, but thus far it looks like the only "on-screen" defeat of a Jedi from a bounty hunter was Jango.

Answer (score 5):

Cad Bane defeated Ahsoka Tano in the *Star Wars: The Clone Wars* episode "Cargo of Doom." However, it's debatable how fair the fight actually was.

Cad Bane also defeated Obi-Wan Kenobi and Quinlan Vos in the *Star Wars: The Clone Wars* episode "Hunt for Ziro."

Bane also killed the Jedi [Bolla Ropal](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Bolla_Ropal) and possibly [Ord Enisense](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Bolla_Ropal), but the combat occurred off-screen, so it's unknown whether he faced them openly or not.

Comment: Looks like he didn't defeat them, just managed to get away from them.

Comment: @TVann He subdued both of them in order to do so.

Comment: He managed to set them back before fleeing, but Obi-Wan and Quinlan were both still up and pursuing him fully (in your vid, at 2:35 you can see it). Also, with Ahsoka, she was a Padawan, not a fully trained Jedi Knight, so it was (arguably) easier.